# MYSQL+Unable to connect from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am using nginx, PHP and MYSQL. I setup a database and a user and I can select it via the MySQL CLI client:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 52
Server version: 5.1.61-0+squeeze1 (Debian)
mysql> use cinema
Database changed
```

However, it seems not to work when I try to connect to it from my php script:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '************');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

The output is:

```
Could not connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' `(using password: NO)`
```

(************ is of course my real password...).

Does anyone have an idea why it says `(using password: NO)` although I clearly use one in my code?

Comment: what about your os and mysql installation?

Comment: Sidenote: `mysql` is not recommended anymore. Use `MySQLi`, or `PDO_MySQL` instead.

Comment: See my post: Server version: 5.1.61-0+squeeze1 (Debian) - let me know if u need to know more details!

Comment: you can access phpmyadmin by this user and password? you run mysql_secure_install?

Comment: ilanco solved it! Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be that [mysql safe mode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sql.safe-mode) is on, and then the password field is ignored.

Comment: Simply great! I wonder why it was On in the first place, but nevermind!